# Deforming relations for a symmetric Frobenius algebra to obtain an algebra of finite global dimension

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

By doing computer experiments with the GAP-package QPA I found a (connected non-semisimple) symmetric quiver algebra $A=KQ/I$ with admissible relations $I$ containing relations of the form $w_1 - w_2$ for two paths $w_i$.

Now I noted that when one replaces a single relation of the form $w_1 - w_2$ by $w_1 - \lambda w_2$ for $\lambda \neq 1,0$ in $I$ one obtains a new quiver algebra that has finite global dimension.
I was surprised that such a thing can happen since a symmetric Frobenius algebra is far from having finite global dimension.

> Question 1: Is there a systematic theory of "deforming" admissible relations in quiver algebras in such a way using parameters $\lambda$? In particular, is there a criterion when a given quiver algebra can be deformed in such a way into another quiver algebra of finite global dimension?

> Question 2: Is there an existing (or easy) example already somewhere in the literature which shows that a symmetric Frobenius algebra can be deformed into an algebra of finite global dimension?

My example is quite complicated and I wonder whether there is an easier example.